# Vertical-align in inline-block container

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

How to align .content in the middle (vertically) without specifying height of .container explicitly?

```
<div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.content {
    height: 50px;
    width: 70px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.one {
    height: 200px;
    width: 20px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: try adding vertical-align: middle for both .one & .content classes

Comment: You have a error in your html...you should close the container div

Comment: not sure. are you looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nykdzeyp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying `vertical-align: middle` to both child elements:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.one {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">text</div>
  <div class="one">text</div>
</div>
```